# Closure Compiler warning with Google Analytics and Facebook Pixel

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function StartThirdPartyScripts() {

    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
        if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
            n.callMethod ?
            n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
        }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
        n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
        t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    }(window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
}
```

The problem is that when I run this in Closure Compiler advanced mode, I got 3 warnings because the number of parameters don't match. Here are the warnings:

```
        WARNING - Function function: called with 5 argument(s). 
        Function requires at least 7 argument(s) and no more than 7 argument(s).
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) { ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     ClosureCompiler/initialjxaz.js:512: WARNING - Suspicious code. The result of 
        the 'not' operator is not being used. !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) { 
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ClosureCompiler/initialjxaz.js:512: 
        WARNING - Function function: called with 4 argument(s). Function requires at 
least 7 argument(s) and no more than 7 argument(s). 
        !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) { ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        ^^^^ 0 error(s), 3 warning(s)
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you show the warnings?  Also, this looks like minimized code, is this really the source code?  And what settings are you compiling with?  Including what externs are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore those warnings. The code has extra function arguments which are not used so Closure-compiler is warning. If the arguments were marked as optional or had default values, then the compiler would not warn.

I also have no idea why they are using the `!` operator in front of that function. It looks like they are using it to protect against concatenated files not have a semi-colon - but I would have just expected them to use `;` for that.

Comment: At the moment, my JS code is 44K lines and compiles without a single warning; took a lot of time to get everything working perfectly. I just added the Google and FB scripts and now there are warnings. Can I remove the extra arguments?

Comment: It's safer to explicitly pass `undefined` at the call site.

Comment: Will that remove the warnings?

Comment: Yes. The number of call arguments needs to match the number of function parameters.

Comment: Ok, will try it in my code and let you know. Thanks, you've helped me several times.

Comment: Passing undefined worked great and resolved the warnings.